# `no `to_substrate_wasm_fn_return_value` in the root` when i run `cargo build` in pallet dir

Tags: pallet

My rust version is :-
[image]
when i was run `cargo build` in this dirextory: https://github.com/VegeBun-csj/Proof-Chain/tree/main/pallets/xclient

i got an error:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your `std` feature declaration in your pallet. There you need to ensure that for every dependency that you imported with `default-features = false` you have added to the `std` feature declaration with `crate/std`.

Comment: thank you sir, i have solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this recently, and the underlying issue was that I had multiple versions of the Substrate git repo being referenced in different `Cargo.toml` files.